# how to rescale binary character image?

Tags: java, image-processing, character

http://cafefiles.naver.net/20130606_179/rise1925_1370463189365uKV60_PNG/%C1%A6%B8%F1_%BE%F8%C0%BD.png

I tried to resize character images by bicubic algorithm in Java.
but as you can see it linked , connectivity of image has broken...
I just made code..

```
public BufferedImage scaleImage(BufferedImage img, int width, int height,
        Color background) {

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();

    try {
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC); 
        //g.setBackground(background);
        //g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, this);

    } finally {
        g.dispose();
    }
return newImage;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: That URL is "Referral Denied".  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Originaly I was just going to say use .getScaledInstance(), but I read an ardicle on good practices with the java Image and Buffered Image api.

https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html

And this is the sorce code that I think you need

```
public static BufferedImage scaleImage(BufferedImage img, int width, int height) {

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,img.getType());

    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
         RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC); 

    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();

    return newImage;
}
```

You were setting the new re-sized image to be a binary (read as black and white ie 1 and 0) image. It is a good practice to always set a re-scaled image to the same type as the image the re-scaling is based off and to change its type with a conversion method.